# SQl Invalid Object

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am having some trouble with my procedure, I have the code working i think, the procedure runs and asks the user for input, the user enters the data which is stored in variables in the procedure which are then inserted into the table. But when I enter everything I am faced with an error. is it even possible to use an insert in a procedure or should I be going a different route?  thanks

My procedure

```
  create or replace PROCEDURE AD_AGENCY_INFO(
v_agency_id IN OUT AD_AGENCY.AGENCY_ID%TYPE,
v_no_of_ad_runs IN OUT AD_AGENCY.NO_OF_AD_RUNS%TYPE,
v_credit_worthy IN OUT AD_AGENCY.CREDIT_WORTHY%TYPE,
v_available_slots IN OUT AD_AGENCY.AVAILABLE_SLOTS%TYPE,
v_status IN OUT AD_AGENCY.STATUS%TYPE
) AS
  BEGIN

SELECT AGENCY_ID, NO_OF_AD_RUNS, CREDIT_WORTHY, AVAILABLE_SLOTS, STATUS 
INTO 
v_agency_id, v_no_of_ad_runs, v_credit_worthy, v_available_slots, v_status 
FROM AD_AGENCY;

INSERT INTO AD_AGENCY (AGENCY_ID, NO_OF_AD_RUNS, CREDIT_WORTHY, AVAILABLE_SLOTS, STATUS) 
VALUES (AGENCY_ID, NO_OF_AD_RUNS, CREDIT_WORTHY, AVAILABLE_SLOTS, STATUS);
INSERT INTO AD (AGENCY_ID) VALUES (AGENCY_ID);


END AD_AGENCY_INFO;
```

How I am calling the procedure

```
DECLARE
 V_AGENCY_ID NUMBER:='&Enter_Agency_ID';
V_NO_OF_AD_RUNS NUMBER:='&Enter_No_of_Ad_Runs';
V_CREDIT_WORTHY CHAR(3):='&Enter_Cedit_Worthy';
  V_AVAILABLE_SLOTS NUMBER:='&Enter_Available_Slots';
V_STATUS CHAR(1):='&Enter_Status';
BEGIN
V_AGENCY_ID := NULL;
V_NO_OF_AD_RUNS := 0;
V_CREDIT_WORTHY := NULL;
V_AVAILABLE_SLOTS := NULL;
V_STATUS := NULL;

AD_AGENCY_INFO(
V_AGENCY_ID => V_AGENCY_ID,
V_NO_OF_AD_RUNS => V_NO_OF_AD_RUNS,
V_CREDIT_WORTHY => V_CREDIT_WORTHY,
V_AVAILABLE_SLOTS => V_AVAILABLE_SLOTS,
V_STATUS => V_STATUS
); 
END;
/
```

The error report

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 14, column 3:
PLS-00905: object DT2113A.AD_AGENCY_INFO is invalid
ORA-06550: line 14, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: Means that procedure didn't compile successfully. So Oracle marked it invalid.

Comment: Removed `SQL SERVER` tag

Comment: The error message is suggesting something is wrong the procedure ad_agency_info.  Are you able to compile ad_agency_info without errors or warnings?

Comment: SELECT *
  FROM user_objects
 WHERE status <> 'VALID';

Comment: hi suzy yes, I can do regular selects from the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably some typos here:

```
INSERT INTO AD_AGENCY (AGENCY_ID, NO_OF_AD_RUNS, CREDIT_WORTHY, AVAILABLE_SLOTS, STATUS) 
VALUES (AGENCY_ID, NO_OF_AD_RUNS, CREDIT_WORTHY, AVAILABLE_SLOTS, STATUS);
--      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Values are ... well values, not column names. Maybe were you thinking to:

```
INSERT INTO AD_AGENCY (AGENCY_ID, NO_OF_AD_RUNS, CREDIT_WORTHY, AVAILABLE_SLOTS, STATUS) 
VALUES (v_agency_id, v_no_of_ad_runs, v_credit_worthy, v_available, v_status);
```

---

BTW, the rest of the code probably still need some thoughts ;)
For example, that code will not work as soon as you will have more than one row in your table:

```
SELECT AGENCY_ID, NO_OF_AD_RUNS, CREDIT_WORTHY, AVAILABLE_SLOTS, STATUS 
INTO 
v_agency_id, v_no_of_ad_runs, v_credit_worthy, v_available_slots, v_status 
FROM AD_AGENCY;
```

Maybe the `WHERE`  clause is missing? And even if so, it will overwrite the `IN` parameter values. Probably not a thing you want at that point...

Comment: thanks for the reply, but that doesnt make sense to me still new to this

Comment: @Hayes121 I've edited my answer to show you a (maybe? probably? at the very least "more") correct `INSERT` statement. If you are very new to PL/SQL, you should definitively take some time to read few more tutorials! PL/SQL might be a difficult beast at first! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not TOO familiar with plsql, but it seems that you are incorrectly calling the procedure from your second block.  Try writing:

```
CALL AD_AGENCY_INFO( 
... 
);
```

Or use Exec, I'm not too sure which:

```
EXEC AD_AGENCY_INFO(
 ...
);
```